# How do I define an on-click event only once in my coffeescript function?

Tags: jquery, onclick, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I want to define a click event, but I'm having trouble getting the click to fire only once when someone clicks on my element.  I have

```
$(document).ready (data) ->
  # Set up order-by click behavior if there are such elements
  alert("defined click") 
  $('[data-order!=""]').click ->
    # Reload the page with an order by clause
    data_val = $(this).data("order") 
    query_data_val = $.url().param('order_by') 
    if query_data_val? && query_data_val.indexOf(data_val) > -1 && query_data_val.indexOf("asc") == -1
      data_val = data_val + " desc"
    new_url = window.location.href.replace( /[\?#].*|$/, "?order_by=" + data_val )   
    alert( new_url )  
    window.location.href = new_url
```

I only see the "defined click" fire once, but I see the second alert ("alert( new_url )") come up ten times when I click only once on one of my data cells.  How do I make the function only fire once when someoen clicks on the data cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first alert fires when the page is loaded, so that only happens once.

There are probably more than one elements on the page that have a data-order attribute not equal to "". In the console run

```
$('[data-order]').length
```

to determine how many nodes your selector is returning.

Your function is setting up an eventListener for all those nodes but will only act on the one that is clicked, because of your use of

```
this
```